# How to prevent @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL}) from saving duplicate duplicate records

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, cascade

In the code provided below, when I'm running HibernateDAOImplTest and duplicate items getting inserted in the item table. I'm saving two customer along with items, there is two item(Soap, Onion) which is common between customers(RAJ and DESH) and I want to insert these two item only once in item table(don't need duplicate) but I need customer-item mapping in customer_item_mapping table.

I'm using

```
org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;
```

==========Tables===========

```
    CREATE TABLE customer_item_mapping ( mapping_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, item_id int(100) NOT NULL, customer_id int(11) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (mapping_id))

CREATE TABLE customer ( customer_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(100) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (customer_id) )

CREATE TABLE item ( item_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(100) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (item_id) )
```

==========First Entity===========

```
@Entity @Cacheable
@Table(name = "customer_item_mapping")
@DynamicInsert(value=true)
@DynamicUpdate(value=true)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class CustomerItemMapping implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3500101963230957017L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "mapping_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer mappingId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "item_id", nullable = false)
private Item item;

@Column(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
private Integer customerId;

}
```

==========Second Entity===========

```
    @Entity @Cacheable
@Table(name = "customer")
@DynamicInsert(value=true)
@DynamicUpdate(value=true)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Customer implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3886876059389214345L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "customer_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer customerId;

@JoinColumn(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String customerName;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "customer_item_mapping", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id"))
@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
private Set<Item> itemSet;

}
```

==========Third Entity===========

```
    @Entity @Cacheable
@Table(name = "item")
@DynamicInsert(value=true)
@DynamicUpdate(value=true)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Item implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3886876059389214345L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "item_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer itemId;

@JoinColumn(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;

public Item(String name){
this.name=name;
}
}
```

==========HibernateDAOImpl===========

```
    package com.myapp.txn.impl.genric.dao;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import com.myapp.txn.exception.PersistenceException;
import com.myapp.txn.genric.dao.HibernateDAO;
public class HibernateDAOImpl {
public Integer saveEntity(String entityType, Object obj, Session session) throws PersistenceException{
Integer id=0;
try {
id = (Integer) session.save(entityType, obj);
}catch (Exception e) {
throw new PersistenceException(e);
}
return id;
}
}
```

==========HibernateDAOImplTest===========

```
    package com.myapp.txn.impl.genric.dao;
public class HibernateDAOImplTest {

@Autowired
private HibernateDAOImpl hibernateDAOImpl;

@Test
public void saveEntityTest(){
Set<Item> itemSet=new HashSet<Item>();
Item item=new Item("Onion");
itemSet.add(item);
item=new Item("Soap");
itemSet.add(item);
item=new Item("Paneer");
itemSet.add(item);
Customer customer=new Customer();
customer.setName("RAJ");
customer.setItemSet(itemSet);
hibernateDAOImpl.saveEntity(customer);

itemSet=new HashSet<Item>();
Item item=new Item("Onion");
itemSet.add(item);
item=new Item("Soap");
itemSet.add(item);
item=new Item("Daaru");
itemSet.add(item);
customer=new Customer();
customer.setName("DESH");
customer.setItemSet(itemSet);
hibernateDAOImpl.saveEntity(customer);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use @ManyToMany mapping. The @ManyToOne or @OneToMAny will not work in your case.

Comment: I guess you can use [this] (http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/) link